# ApacheNiFi processor updateAttribute runs too many tasks,but I just one flowfile tranfers to it

Tags: apache-nifi, processor, update-attributes

ApacheNiFi processor updateAttribute runs too many tasks,but I just have only one flowfile tranfers to it

[here is my nifi group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QoWT7.png)

Answer (score 0):

I know why。

when my upstream processor routes to the relation of retry, penalizes the flow file, this causing it to wait Penalty Duration(30 seconds).

But,this trigger down processor continuous cycle of data acquisition。